# Finding tabs and white spaces inside the file in Perl

Tags: php, perl

We are doing the our code review manually. It's eating our more time to review the each and every file. We are checking below generic items for all the files. It would be good if any automated script in Perl / Php for code review.

1. List out the total number of tabs used inside the files.
2. List out the total number of white spaces inside the files.

Kindly help to create automated tool for code review.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm amused by the idea of you or someone manually counting the tabs.

Count tabs:

```
perl -ne '$c += () = /\t/g; END{print qq{$c}}' file.pl
```

or

```
perl -ne '$c += tr/\t//; END {print qq{$c}}' file.pl
```

And similarly for white spaces:

```
perl -ne '$c += tr/ //; END {print qq{$c}}' file.pl
```

Comment: @MathiyazhahanMaheswaran You can thank Miller by accepting his answer if it helped resolve your question. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more details.

Comment: The versions using tr// are more efficient